# What is the more proper alternative to "my bad"?

Tags: phrase-request, responses

When people admit mistakes they tend to use the phrase "my bad". I found that it is an informal way in North America. Could anyone help me with a better alternative?

Comment: Perhaps "my fault".

Comment: I find this question odd because you say: make a mistake. Surely, that would bring you to "My mistake".

Comment: Why the close vote? Vlad is not asking for an explanation, but for a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“my bad” is slang and very informal.

“I made a mistake” or “that was my mistake” is formal, and just “my mistake” is informal.

The point of all these variants is to take ownership of the mistake: it was mine, not yours.

If you want to avoid saying who made the mistake or it’s not relevant, use passive voice: “a mistake was made”.

Comment: Note that "a mistake was made" (or more commonly the plural: "mistakes were made") will be seen as evasive. It's practically a cliché at this point for a politician to trot that line out whenever the public learns of something embarrassing or damaging.